# C# WPF Como separar uma string longa em várias posições de um Array?

Tags: c#, array, string, wpf, xaml

Preciso criar um getter e um setter para 14 propriedades da Model que serão utilizadas para fazer Binding no xaml. 
As propriedades vem daqui: tenho um campo de uma tabela de banco de dados onde ele carrega uma string muito longa que contém informações para 14 textboxes na minha tela (userControl). 
A string deve ser "quebrada" em 14 partes de 50 caracteres, cada uma das partes de 50 caracteres deve ser uma posição dentro de um array.
O getter separa a string e o setter a junta novamente.
Isso é tudo o que sei sobre esses dados.
Por enquanto tenho esse método getter, mas me parece incompleto (não consigo enxergar muito bem o que falta pois sou novato tanto na programção quanto na linguagem - admito que travei e não sei o que fazer)

```
public string[] GetFlagInJobMvTit(int startPosition, int stringLength)
    {
        StringBuilder sbJobMvTit = new StringBuilder(50);
        startPosition = 0;

        string[] TitArray = new string[14];
        for (int i=0; i < 14; i++)
        {
            JobMvTit = sbJobMvTit.ToString();
            NotifyPropertyChanged("job_mv_tit");
            TitArray[i] = JobMvTit;
            startPosition += stringLength;
        }
        return TitArray;
    }
```

Agradeço desde já

Comment: A sua pergunta parece incompleta; Na verdade parece ter muita informação irrelevante, mas falta o que você está com dúvida, o que podemos ajudar. Dando uma analisada o código parece não fazer sentido, mas pode ser só que eu eu não entendi objetivo.

Answer (score 1):

Forma simples de dividir a string usando expressões regulares, lembrando que com o substring tem de se validar sempre o tamanho, se a string tiver tamanho inferior a 14*50 haverá erro.

```
var stringGiganteDoBanco = "123141231231245123124512312312451231245124312412341212314123123124512312451231231245123124512431241234121231412312312451231245123123124512312451243124123412";

var arrayStrings = Regex.Split(stringGiganteDoBanco, "(?<=\\G.{50})");
```

Comment: Não sabia que Regex fazia isso. Muito boa sua resposta. :o

Comment: Regex faz mágica ;)

Answer (score 0):

Também achei sua dúvida meio incompleta, mas acredito que esteja procurando algo assim:

```
public string[] DividirString(string str)
{
    if(str.Length != 50*14)
        throw new ArgumentException("String inválida", "str");

    var partes = new string[14];
    for (int parteAtual = 0, i = 0; parteAtual < 14; parteAtual++)
    {
        partes[parteAtual] = str.Substring(i, 50);
        i += 50;
    }

    return partes;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz essa classe de exemplo, que atende a sua necessidade.
Não fiz tratamentos de erros, tão pouco a origem dos dados.

```
        public class Teste
        {
            public Teste()
            {
                //Chamo o método de carregar a List<>
                Carregar();
            }

            //String de exemplo com tamanho 700
            string textoMuitoGrande = "".PadRight(50, 'A') + "".PadRight(50, 'B') + "".PadRight(50, 'C') + "".PadRight(550, 'X');

            //Lista que armazena todas as propriedades
            List<string> _propriedades;

            //Encapsulamento propriedade A
            public string PropriedadeA { get { return _propriedades[0]; } set { _propriedades[0] = value; } }

            //Encapsulamento propriedade B
            public string PropriedadeB { get { return _propriedades[1]; } set { _propriedades[1] = value; } }


            //Método para obter todo o conteúdo da string concatenada
            public string JuntarTudo()
            {
                string retorno = "";
                foreach (string s in _propriedades)
                    retorno += s;

                return retorno;
            }

            //Método que divide a string e carrega a List<>
            public void Carregar()
            {
                _propriedades = new List<string>();
                int x = 0;
                for (int i =0; i < 14;i++)
                {
                    _propriedades.Add(textoMuitoGrande.Substring(x, 50));
                    x += 50;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um método de extensão da String para ajudar nesta tarefa.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace StackOverflow
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string helloWorld = "Hello World! Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!Hello World!";
            var stringDivided = helloWorld.SplitParts(10);
            foreach (var part in stringDivided)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{ part }\n");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static class StringExtensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<String> SplitParts(this String s, Int32 partLength)
        {
            if (s == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("s");
            if (partLength <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentException("Part must be positive.", "partLength");

            for (var i = 0; i < s.Length; i += partLength)
                yield return s.Substring(i, Math.Min(partLength, s.Length - i));
        }
    }
}
```